# Why isn't my code detecting the digit in my string. I'm using regex

Tags: java, regex, string, character, match

This is my code. I am looking for any digit in the word I chose, but when my finder looks through my word it returns false, but there clearly is a digit in my word.

```
package payrollprinter;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PayRollPrinter {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String word = "7";

        // convert the string to a pattern
        Pattern wordPattern = Pattern.compile(word);

        // now I look for digits in my word
        Matcher finder = wordPattern.matcher("\\d");
        boolean b = finder.find();
        System.out.println(b);
    }

}
```

Comment: `mi.matcher(month);` and `Pattern.compile("\\d");`. `.matcher()` needs the input string and `Pattern.compile` needs the regex pattern.

Comment: Inverse the pattern and the String maybe, follow the doc  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: Why the downvotes, please? It’s a good beginner’s question. It has minimal, ocmplete and verifiable example, it has expected behaviour and how observed behaviour differs.

Comment: I agree with @OleV.V. except that this could be a RT*M. Documentation should be enough to find the problem. But as a Rookie, I was not the first to open the documentation either ;)

Answer (score 0):

As has been said in the comments already, you had accidentally swapped the pattern, `\d`, and the word, `7`.

```
    String word = "7";

    // translate the pattern so Java can work with it
    Pattern wordPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d");

    // now I look for a digit in my word
    Matcher finder = wordPattern.matcher(word);
    boolean b = finder.find();
    System.out.println(b);
```

Output:

> true